# Parsing string during fragment creation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, fragment

in an application , I wish I would pass a string fragment and display it in a toast.
The problem is with my code, the creation of the fragment I have a toast that appears, but empty ...
I do not understand where did my problem ( it's the first time I try to do that )

My code :
*MainActivity :*

```
       public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
 private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

private CharSequence mUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);

}


@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment objFragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, fragment_test.class);
            intent.putExtra("message", "test");
            objFragment = new fragment_test();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new menu2_Fragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new menu3_Fragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            objFragment = new menu4_Fragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            objFragment = new menu5_Fragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            objFragment = new menu6_Fragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            objFragment = new menu8_Fragment();
            break;
        case 7:
            objFragment = new menu9_Fragment();
            break;
        case 8:
            objFragment = new menu7_Fragment();
            break;
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}




/*@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}*/}
```

Fragment_test :

```
public class fragment_test extends Fragment {
View rootview;
@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml1, container, false);

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    return rootview;
}}
```

thx in advance

ps : sorry for my english french

Comment: use `Fragment.setArguments` to send data to fragments. use `intent` to send data between activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, objFragment).commit();
```

Replace with

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, objFragment).commit();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(key, value);
objFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Write below code in your another activity

```
if (getArguments() != null)
{
    m_searchText = getArguments().getString(Key);
}
```

Comment: if it worked for you then can you please accept the answer so that it can be useful to others.